# missing commits after git rebase

Tags: git, github, rebase

```
A-B-C  Master
 \D-E  Feature
```

After executing a `rebase` command `git checkout feature` -> `git rebase master` all my commits from `feature` branch disappears so I have `A-B-C` commits. `feature` branch looks like `master` after rebasing. Also rebasing doesn't give any error but it doesn't show 'commits are replayed' message which I think usually it shows during rebasing. Do you know what could have caused this behaviour?

Once I've noticed my commits disappeared I ran the following command to find the missing code in git history: `git rev-list --all | xargs git grep expression` This command returned a commit hash but this hash was not present when I run git log (because of rebase). If I do `git reset --hard missing-hash` I can see the original (correct) `feature` code again. Running `rebase master` recreates same problem again.

**EDIT:** I've just noticed I have some extra commits like `WIP on commit-message` and `index on commit-message` when I do `git reset --hard missing-hash` Can it be related with `git stash / git stash apply`

Comment: ahh, try this: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html

Comment: I know how I could get my files back. Also 'merge master' works as well. I want to find out what might have caused such behaviour of rebase command

Comment: Are those commits D and E somehow identical in their content to the commits of master? (in which case, they would be skipped during a rebase)

Comment: They are not identical to master, otherwise I wouldn't notice anything missing in the code after rebasing. P.S. I did 'git commit --amend' several times before rebasing.

Comment: I agree with VonC that the only way you would not have seen rewinding and replaying during your rebase is if the common ancestor commit between master and feature were C(E), and B-C were the same commits as D-E.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just so were on the same page about how rebases work. In your example, git is basically trying to add and D and E after C one by one. The rebase commits on D & E will not be the originals, instead they will be clones with new hashes. The original will still exist, but will simply be dangling with no branch referencing them (garbage collection will delete them eventually). After a rebase, you can see the "original" version of the rebased commits by looking at `git log ORIG_HEAD`

However, exceptions can take place in this process. Git will intelligently skip any commits that are already in the "base" (master, in this case) - this can happen a branch gets merged, reverted, then remerged.

It will also skip any commits if it finds that the commits being added to the base identically match, in their content - commits that are already in the history - even if the hashes are different - this can happen if a branch is merged, rebase, then merged again.

I suspect one of a few situations.

1. Your feature branch may have already been merged into master.
2. Your feature branch already matches master.

1) git branch --contains feature

This will list all branches which contain your feature branch in their history. If master is in that list, then your branch is already merged. Nothing to do here.

Theres a few reasons this might not seem right though.

One reason is that you may not see your changes in the current master code. This could be for a few reasons. If the branch had been previously merged into master, and then reverted, then the commits are already there, but negated - even if remerged those reverted commits will not return - you would need to revert the actual revert commit.

2) git checkout feature; git rebase --keep-empty feature

The --keep-empty will force git to keep your commits even if they don't contain any "new" content or changes. This isn't a fix or workaround, but if you see these commits in your history after doing this - then it means your commits arent being lost. They are getting skipped intentionally. You can decide for yourself if you want to keep the empty ones.

If this is the case, then I would look to see if this branch has been merged in the past. It may have been merged as part of a different branch for example. Maybe Bob thought he needed your work from the `feature` branch in his `bobs_feature` branch - his branch made it to master before yours and now your branch is basically irrelevant. Another case might be that it was merged in the past into master, and then reverted. The answer here is to revert the revert commit itself - sort of like hitting redo after hitting an undo.

Comment: Thanks for explaining possible reasons.The workflow I follow is create feature branch from master for each jira ticket.Then rebase feature regularly when other tickets(my own or others)were merged into the master.If I have some ongoing changes I do git stash->rebase master->git stash apply.Im pretty sure I did smth which is not what I thought I was doing.Maybe applied stash on wrong branch or smth else (If I new I wouldn't ask).From what you wrote this looks like quite likely:'If the branch had been previously merged into master and then reverted then the commits are already there but negated'

Comment: And on this feature I did several 'rebases' from master for sure.

Comment: I'll try to go through git history/reflogs to check if I can figure out if smth you've mentioned happened. But it contains too many branches and commits so it's quite difficult/time consuming. At least now I have a clue what might has happened instead of being clueless next time I see that (It happened not the first time to me)

Comment: If your branch was merged in the past, and your current branch has not been rebased, try the --contains flag with a has that is in your feature branch. This will at least confirm the suspicion. If the branch has been rebased, the commit hashes will have changed and the search wont work.